# Ruby on Rails project ->Error by "cap production deploy" -> ERROR rbenv: 2.2.2 is not installed or not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm experiencing an error by trying to execute "cap production deploy"

```
    ERROR rbenv: 2.2.2 is not installed or not found in /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
    # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
    gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
    # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
    gem 'sqlite3'
    # Use SCSS for stylesheets
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
    # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
    # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
    # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
    # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
    gem 'jquery-rails'

    gem 'turbolinks'

    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
    # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
    gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

    # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
    # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

    # Use Unicorn as the app server
    # gem 'unicorn'

    # Use Capistrano for deployment
    # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

    group :development, :test do

    gem 'byebug'



     # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
    gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

    # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
    gem 'spring'
    end
    group :development do
      gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.4.0'
      gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.3'
      gem 'capistrano-rbenv' #'~> 2.2.0'
      gem 'capistrano-passenger'
    end
```

This is my Capfile:

```
    # Load DSL and set up stages
    require 'capistrano/setup'

    # Include default deployment tasks
    require 'capistrano/deploy'


    require 'capistrano/rbenv'
    set :rbenv_type, :user # or :system, depends on your rbenv setup
    set :rbenv_ruby, '2.2.0'

    require 'capistrano/bundler'
    require 'capistrano/rails'
    require 'capistrano/passenger'

    # Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
    Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

This is my deploy.rb file:

```
    # config valid only for current version of Capistrano
    lock '3.4.0'

    set :application, 'blank1'
    set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:r2artene/blank1.git'

    # setup rvm.
    set :rbenv_type, :system
    set :rbenv_ruby, '2.2.0'


    # Default branch is :master
    # ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

    # Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
    set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/blank1'

    # Default value for :scm is :git
    # set :scm, :git

    # Default value for :format is :pretty
    # set :format, :pretty

    # Default value for :log_level is :debug
    # set :log_level, :debug

    # Default value for :pty is false
    # set :pty, true

    # Default value for :linked_files is []
    # set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

    # Default value for linked_dirs is []
    # set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log',                 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')

    set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml}
    set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}


    # Default value for default_env is {}
    # set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

    # Default value for keep_releases is 5
    # set :keep_releases, 5

    namespace :deploy do

      after :restart, :clear_cache do
        on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
          # Here we can do anything such as:
          # within release_path do
          #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
          # end
        end
      end

    end
```

at command "ruby -v" on local machine the result I get is:

```
    ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]
```

at command "ruby -v" on deploment server the result I get is:

```
    ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: Are you using RVM in addition to Rbenv? Run `rvm notes` and see if you get any output.

Comment: this is the result:/ruby/blank1$ rvm notes
In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io

Installation Notes:

  * If you wish to disable the project .rvmrc file functionality, set
    rvm_project_rvmrc=0 in either /etc/rvmrc or ~/.rvmrc.
    then log out and back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're experiencing a conflict between RVM and Rbenv, where RVM is still maintaining a reference to Ruby 2.2.2 someplace (maybe a bash profile), even though you appear to have only Ruby 2.2.0 installed.

RVM and rbenv are [incompatible](http://www.rubyinside.com/rbenv-a-simple-new-ruby-version-management-tool-5302.html) with one another, so you're going to have to decide which tool you want to use to manage your libraries. Removing one or the other should solve your problem.

To uninstall RVM, run `rvm implode`, which completely uninstalls RVM.

To uninstall rbenv, `rm` your `.rbenv` directory and remove references to rbenv from your shell's script.